# How to hide keyboard layout indicator in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3?

Tags: keyboard-layout, indicator, gnome-shell

I've tried a lot of workarounds and extensions, but I just simply can't hide keyboard layout indicator.

[image: This thing]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can remove all input sources but the one you want to use.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  I need to be able to switch to another language, because english is not my native language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/) (now supports GNOME shell v3.26, the one included in Ubuntu 17.10).

This extension provides option to hide/show indicators individually, you'll be able to hide the keyboard layout indicator in particular.

[image]

Comment: Pretty good extension!