# How can I hide the KDE Connect system tray icon?

Tags: icons, system-tray, kde-connect

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. I've installed the KDE Connect application. (FWIW I do not have KDE Connect Indicator installed as the application seems to be working okay without it.) But it gives me an annoying little phone icon in the system tray (top-right corner of the screen) which I can't seem to get rid of - if I right-click on it, the only option is "Configure" but that menu isn't helpful. How can I hide this icon?

Here's a screenshot of my system tray with the offending icon highlighted in red:
[image]

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978172/how-to-hide-keyboard-layout-indicator-in-ubuntu-17-10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pomsky suggested in a comment, the "Icon Hider" Gnome extension does the trick.